# Selection background the same as text color of the current text block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The same mechanism as in terminal: selection should be the same color as the unselected text color and the text becomes white, when selected. Is there a way in HTML (+CSS/JS) to get the color of every block and use it as selection color for this block?

[image: For example Terminator]

**Update**: Despite some people getting overly nervous and dissing my question only because they themselves didn't really understand it and came up with a solution to an entirely different problem, I got some progress here. I found out, that the `::selection` tag could be combined with classes, so the only problem now is to iterate through the list of elements and classes and create a `::selection` rule for each of them, using their color as background color for selection. Now I understand in what direction it should go further. But if you get a working script before I answer my own question, be my guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the script:

```
$('*').each(function(index){
    color = $(this).css('color');
    id = 'id' + index.toString()
    $(this).attr('id', id);
    rule = '#' + id + '::selection {background-color:' + color + '}';
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule, 0);
});
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Perhaps, it could work quicker with vanilla JS, but I'm not sure how to do that. Plus, I'm OK with this little lag on load.

Answer (score 1):

The below shows an example of how you can apply a universal selection rule for all elements, you may want to edit the colors etc as you see fit.

## [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/d6nDJ/)

HTML

```
<div>Div Text</div>
<span>Span Text</span>
<h2>H2 Text</h2>
<section>Section Text</section>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:black;
}
div {
    color:red;
}
span {
    color:blue;
}
h2 {
    color:orange;
}
section {
    color:green;
}
::selection {
    color:inherit;
    background:white;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I know about the `::selection` tag and what it can do. My problem is that I want the background-color of the selection to "inherit" the color of the element, i.e. red text should have red selection background and brown - brown. The color of the selected text may be white in this case.

Comment: I'm now looking into scripted solution, but if you know how to do that with pure HTML/CSS - I'd be glad to hear.